# UWP - can't interact with localhost IBM Sametime

Tags: deployment, uwp, localhost, sametime

I have a UWP application that should interact with local Sametime client through REST API that is hosted on localhost by I faced with the issue - that's restricted to call localhost from UWP app.

There are a few of solutions:

1. Create a proxy(e.g. WCF) that will interact with localhost.
2. Execute "CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -p=SIDHERE" in cmd on each client machine.

But I need a solution that will allow me to use just only a single package file to deploy my application. So may be there is any more elegant solution to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could refer uwp [appservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). This is a [blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/) that use wpf as proxy and communication with uwp appservice.

Comment: It seems to be a solution of my case. Thanks!)

Comment: Unfortunately not cause app service can't interact with localhost too.